# How do you increase pensize on every iteration for Python turtle?

Tags: python, python-2.x, turtle-graphics

I have code that makes shapes dependent on the number of sides input but I also want it to automatically increase pensize on every iteration without asking for values in the console. When helping me can you please apply changes to my code because I really struggle to merge foreign code into my own. Here's my code:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen() 
Mo = turtle.Turtle()

numsides = int(input("How many sides would you like your shape to have (3- 
8)?"))

if numsides == 3:
    shape_name = "triangle"
if numsides == 4:
    shape_name = "square"
if numsides == 5:
    shape_name = "pentagon"
if numsides == 6:
    shape_name = "hexagon"
if numsides == 7:
    shape_name = "heptagon"
if numsides == 8:
    shape_name = "octagon"


print("That'll be a " + shape_name + ".")

howbig = int(input("What size lines would you like: "))

for myMoves in range(numsides):
    Mo.forward(howbig)
    Mo.left(360/numsides)
```

Comment: get the actual pensize (or choose on) _before_ your loop, increase it and set it to be used _inside_ the loop? meaning ... increase `howbig` by 1 inside your loop omn each loop iteration?

Comment: @PatrickArtner thx for the advice, i've tried but it tells me that forward can only have one command not two.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does what you describe -- if it doesn't, please revise your question to explain what "automatically increase in pensize in every iteration" means:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

numsides = int(input("How many sides would you like your shape to have (3 - 8)? "))

if numsides == 3:
    shape_name = "triangle"
elif numsides == 4:
    shape_name = "square"
elif numsides == 5:
    shape_name = "pentagon"
elif numsides == 6:
    shape_name = "hexagon"
elif numsides == 7:
    shape_name = "heptagon"
elif numsides == 8:
    shape_name = "octagon"

print("That'll be a", shape_name + ".")

howbig = int(input("What size lines would you like: "))

window = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

for width, myMoves in enumerate(range(numsides), start=1):
    turtle.width(width)
    turtle.forward(howbig)
    turtle.left(360 / numsides)

turtle.hideturtle()

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

> the console says How many sides would you like your shape to have (3 -
>   8)? 8 ("That'll be a", 'octagon.')

For Python 2, we need to make some changes:

```
from turtle import Turtle, mainloop

numsides = int(raw_input("How many sides would you like your shape to have (3 - 8)? "))

if numsides == 3:
    shape_name = "triangle"
elif numsides == 4:
    shape_name = "square"
elif numsides == 5:
    shape_name = "pentagon"
elif numsides == 6:
    shape_name = "hexagon"
elif numsides == 7:
    shape_name = "heptagon"
elif numsides == 8:
    shape_name = "octagon"

print("That'll be a " + shape_name + ".")

howbig = int(raw_input("What size lines would you like: "))

turtle = Turtle()

width = 1

for myMoves in range(numsides):
    turtle.width(width)
    turtle.forward(howbig)
    turtle.left(360 / numsides)

    width += 1

turtle.hideturtle()

mainloop()
```

The cascade of `if ... elif ... elif ...` statements should be a dictionary but I'm going to assume you haven't reached those yet in your learning.  I rearranged the code so the Q & A gets done before the turtle window can obscure the console.

Comment: thx for the help. When I run it the console says                                                     How many sides would you like your shape to have (3 - 8)?  8
("That'll be a", 'octagon.')
What size lines would you like:  10
ValueError: Keyword arguments are not supported by this function on line 25 and it doesn't draw the shape. Any extra help you can provide.

Comment: @NourAlaas, it sound like you're using Python 2 -- my answer was based on Python 3.  I've added a modified Python 2/3 friendly solution to my answer and will retag your question accordingly.

Comment: works amazingly thank you!!! Great to have people in the community as a helping hand really appreciated.